# HTML and CSS : Difference between glyphicon and image

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a button to refresh a value on my HTML page and I put a refresh icon inside the button.
And by doing this I saw that i could use a glyphicon :

```
<button id="button_reload" onclick=reload()><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
```

or use an image :

CSS:

```
.buttn{
background:transparent url(/reload.png) no-repeat left; }
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button_reload" onclick=reload() class="buttn"></button>
```

What is the big difference between the two since they are both working ?

Comment: glyphicons are more scalable than pngs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case main difference is that you set your custom image as a `background` of the `button`.

In case of glyphicon it is not a `background` but an `image` inside of the `button`.

What follows both will have different set of properties that can be applied to them and will behave in a different way. Glyphicon will behave as an `image` and your case will behave as a `background`.

For example in your case you can use properties like: `background-repeat`, `background-size`, `background-position` which you can't use for a glyphicon and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks you ! It's answering my question

Answer (score 3):

Glyphicons are a set of character implemented into a font family (Glyphicons Halflings) inside the **bootstrap** package.  So they are characters not images  and do not support background properties such as `background-repeat` or `background-size`.

If you have used bootstrap in your project you no more need to use image icons with extra size.

this is the css behind glyphicons:

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.glyphicon-refresh:before {
    content: "\e031";
}
```